# Why does echo $word|tr -c $guessed _ add an extra _ at the end

Tags: bash, tr

to make hangman i replace a words letters with "_" i do this using

```
echo $word|tr -c $guessed _
```

which works but it creates an extra _ at the end of the word. How do i get rid of him?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found out on my own. The extra _ is the "return" that echo produces replaced by _

```
echo -n $word|tr -c $guessed _
```

this works like a charm

Comment: FYI -- `echo -n` isn't a POSIX-standardized option. You're better off using `printf %s "$word"`, which is guaranteed to work on all POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: ...of course, on bash, you don't even need that: `new_word=${word//$guessed/_}`; all built-in functionality, much faster than using an external tool such as `tr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` puts in a newline character at the end of its output, which `tr` is converting. This is often the desired behavior, hence it being the default. Imagine `echo hello` on the terminal; you want a newline there so your prompt returns.

You can use the `-n` option to `echo` to fix the above behavior. This information can be found in `man 1 echo`:

```
-n     do not output the trailing newline
```